# Using FactoryGirl for a controller test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot

I want to test my Users#show controller. How can I use FactoryGirl to create test data to be passed into my controller?

In "spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb":

```
describe UsersController do
    describe "GET #show" do
        it "assigns the requested user to @user" do
            user = Factory(:user) # How do I do this using FactoryGirl?
            get :show, id: user
            assigns(:user).should eq(user)
        end
   end
end
```

In "spec/factories/users.rb"

```
require 'faker'

FactoryGirl.define do 
    factory :user do
        email { Faker::Internet.email }
    end

    # Replace email with nil. Apparently all other attributes defer to the 
    # original :user factory.
    factory :invalid_user do
        email nil
    end
end
```

Comment: The tutorial I'm following simply uses `Factory(:user)` but I believe it's outdated - http://everydayrails.com/2012/04/07/testing-series-rspec-controllers.html

Comment: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md

Comment: use `create(:user)` or `build(:user)`

Comment: Thanks @Bartosz I was also checking the docs, I tried `build(:user)` but it gives this error `No route matches {:id=>nil, :controller=>"alpha_users", :action=>"show"}`. In my factory, I don't set an "id" explicitly, since that is auto-incremented in my db. Does this need to be explicitly set?

Comment: It's an exception from the next line, you should do `get :show, id: user.id`

Comment: And because `build` does not create a database object, you'll encounter similar problems. Consider using `create` or you'll have to stub the queries sometimes.

Comment: Thanks, used create(), but still get this odd error from the `get :show, id: user.id` line - `undefined method `update_attribute' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Now that's the controller exception. Paste in its content.

Comment: @DonnyP note, that you also should have InvalidUser model existed.

Comment: @majioa, sorry what do you mean by "existed"?

Comment: That means that you should have file app/models/invalid_user.app with defined `InvalidUser` defined inside it.

Comment: @majioa, I'm assuming you mean app/models/user.rb? Not .app? Also I'm testing an invalid user. Why would I create a model for something that shouldn't work?

Comment: @Bartosz, thanks it was a controller bug! Hurrah tests. One last question if you want. For `assigns(:user).should eq(user)` I'm getting an error that `:user` is nil, despite expecting the proper `user` object.

Comment: place your `:invalid_user` factory inside `:user` scope or add a `class: User` param

Comment: as for the `assigns` question, I'm not sure what the problem is. Controller content would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To wrap things up:

Use `create(:user)` or `build(:user)` as shown in [latest docs](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md) instead of `Factory(:user)`.

`build(:user)` does not save the object to database therefore you will probably have to stub controller's queries. It's faster though.

To pass the id of not persisted user you'll have to do `get :show, id: user.id` instead of `get :show, id: user`

Comment: By the way if you want the object to not touch the database at all use build_stubbed(:user), build(:user) still enters associated objects into the database.